# Tab Order in ASP.NET MVC 3 Helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tab-ordering

How can I use Tab Order property for following code:

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost)                
</td>
```

I tried this:

```
<td tabindex=1>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost)                
</td>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The last time SO has seen @AbdullahSaqib was 5 days after this question was asked in 2011

Answer (score 14):

You can also specify the same html attribute in the helper itself as follows.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost, new { tabindex = 1 })
```

Comment: This does not work in `EditorFor`, a second parameter in EditorFor of type object is used to build View Data not add HTML attributes per the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462.aspx

Comment: You can't specify additional parameters in the EditorFor.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was using TextBoxFor and just replaced the helper name thinking EditorFor would work the same way.

Answer (score 10):

As a contrast to @Stuy1974's right answer, if you don't want to leave the `EditorFor` solution, you're going to have to wire up your own [Editor Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx).

```
@ModelType SomeApp.ViewModels.SomeNiftyViewModel 

// be sure to include the TabIndex info in the ViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost, new { tabindex = model.TabIndex })
```

You can also use the ViewData parameter already passed to the editor template directly rather than adding the tab index to the model:

```
// In the main view
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { TabIndex = 3 })

// In the editor template
@{ int tabIndex = (ViewData["TabIndex"] as int?) ?? 0; }
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { tabindex = tabIndex })
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost,  new { htmlAttributes = new { tabindex = 34 } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, allowing you to retain the EditorFor, is to set the tab index in javascript after the page has loaded with something like:

```
var myEditorFor = document.getElementById("MyEditorForId");

if (myEditorFor != null) {
    myEditorFor.setAttribute("tabindex","18")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately @Html.EditorFor method doesn't provide the ability to add HTML attributes.  You can add these via a more specific method call.  In the above case I'd use -

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost, new { tabindex = 1 })`

Comment: He doesn't have to move away from the EditorFor. He could just as easily create an Editor Template.