# What event should I use?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is I have a textbox and after that I have button on the keypress of the tab from the textbox it should go to the button on next tab but am unable do it can anyone help me in solving this issue? My platform is asp.net mvc.

Comment: Do you mean TabIndex?[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679013/tab-order-in-asp-net-mvc-3-helpers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679013/tab-order-in-asp-net-mvc-3-helpers)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're looking for `tabindex`. However, be careful with that, because once you start specifying tab indexes, you're responsible for *all* tabbing on the page. Make sure you don't break tabbing to important parts of the page like the site nav, as many users with disabilities depend on tab to navigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tabindex you can set the order of elements that receive focus by pressing the tab.

```
<!--Press tab on test1 to go to button-->
<input tabindex="1" id="test1" />
<input tabindex="3" id="test2" />
<button tabindex="2">MyButton</button>
```