# Tab key doesnt move to the next textbox which is in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page in that I have multiple partial views. Now with the press of `tab key` I'm not able to move to the text box of another partial view. Can you suggest me something? (I am new to the C# and ASP NET)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at setting the tab index of the field? There is an html5 attribute. This is probably an older mvc version, but should still work.

[Tab Order in ASP.NET MVC 3 Helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679013/tab-order-in-asp-net-mvc-3-helpers)